# What does it mean when there is a comma inside an array declaration? e.g. float[,]

Tags: c#, arrays, declaration

I have some code I'm trying to understand while learning C#.  I do not understand what I even need to search Google for to get here, but the code is as follows:

```
float[,] heightAll = terData.GetHeights(0, 0, allWidth, allHeight);
```

Why does the array declaration have a comma in between the brackets?

Comment: That's c#'s way of declaring a 2D array

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That would be a two-dimensional array. You can also specify more dimensions:

[Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

Each comma adds an additional dimension to the array [,] = 2 dimensional [,,] = 3 dimensional ...

Answer (score 2):

That the array is multi-dimensional - two-dimensional in your case.

Answer (score 2):

It means it is a multidimensional array.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).